# Getting tilde (~) in vue router chunks

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-router

I am using webpackChunkName to give names to the build files (chunks). I same two global routes (`path: /`) and different child routes of each.

After the build, I see can some of the chunks have a tilde sign in them and I haven’t added that. For example

```
dist/js/AccountManagement~Login~Register.dec3aad2.js
```

The `AccountManagement` is in a separate child route and log in and Register are different routes of the same parent route.

Here is my trimmed vue route file

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: () => import("@layouts/dashboard.vue"),
    children: [
      {
        path: "/account/:page",
        name: "Account",
        meta: {
          requiresAuth: true,
          title: "My Account",
        },
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "AccountManagement" */ "@page/profile/MyAccount.vue"),
      },
    ],
  },

  {
    path: "/",
    component: () => import("@layouts/headers.vue"),
    children: [
      {
        path: "/login",
        name: "Login",
        meta: {
          requiresAuth: false,
          title: "Login - Inline Checkout",
        },
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Login" */ "@page/authentication/Login.vue"),
      },
      {
        path: "/reset-password",
        name: "ForgotPassword",
        meta: {
          requiresAuth: false,
          title: "Password Reset - Inline Checkout",
        },
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "ForgotPassword" */ "@page/authentication/ForgotPassword.vue"),
      },
      {
        path: "/register",
        name: "Register",
        meta: {
          requiresAuth: false,
          title: "Register - Inline Checkout",
        },
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Register" */ "@page/authentication/Register.vue"),
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

All I need is to remove this Tilde sign and unwanted name, in this case, `~Login~Register`.